Conditional formatting using vlookups and dates
I’m trying to set up conditional formatting that uses vlookup to check a date against a tag, and if that date is less than a specific date, highlights it green. See attached data as example.
In the example, there are some tags (that I’ve called months for argument sake) and some dates. I’m grouping the tags under a set date, and would like to use conditional formatting to vlookup the tag against its date (I.e. the date under ‘set 1’ or ‘set 2’ and so on) and then compare the dates to drive the formatting.
Thanks in advance!
Hereby an image:


What have you tried so far?

Hi. I’ve tried =(VLOOKUP(A10,A10:C10,2,FALSE))<A9), which doesn’t seem to quite work. Also would like to be able to move different tags under different sets and for it to be intelligent in terms of relative cell referencing.

[edit] that into your question. Now from just that, it might help to lock your cell references (add $), although from your image I can't tell what's what.

You need to consider the few rules:


For VLOOKUP, the sought table should be ordered by the first field.
For the conditional formatting (CF) formula for a range of cells, you need to correctly define absolute and relative addressing:

=VLOOKUP(A10,$A$1:$B$5,2,TRUE)<A$9


For the CF formula for a range of cells, you need to correctly define the formula against the cell which is currently active.

When defining the CF formula for "$A$10:$C$11" while A10 is active:

Lookup value address (A10) should relative since we need to address the cell the CF is applied for.
Table array address should be absolute ($A$1:$C$5) since it's always the same.
Value to compare (A$9) should be relative in columns and absolute in rows since it's always in the same column but in 9th row.


How is it going?
